# Where could I find free PostScript Type 1 font?

Tags: fonts

Where could I find free PostScript Type 1 fonts? Nowadays, the font are either TrueType or OpenType format. There are few Type 1 fonts.

Thanks.

Comment: .................gooogle..............

Answer (score 1):

I believe ghostscript comes with a bunch of postscipt type 1 fonts.

http://www.ghostscript.com/

http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Fonts.htm